# SimpleDateFormat not reversible?

Tags: date, java-7

The following code is not behaving as expected when converting a data to a string, and back to a date under java 7 here:

```
final long epochTime = 1489669024142L;
String pattern = "ddMMMYY HH:mm";
final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
final Date inputDate = new Date(epochTime);
final String date1 = format.format(inputDate);
final Date date2 = format.parse(date1);
```

The execution of this gives me:

```
inputDate: Thu Mar 16 13:57:04 CET 2017
date1: 16Mar17 13:57
date2: Sun Jan 01 13:57:00 CET 2017
```

Clearly, there is a good 3 months difference here, while I expected a 4 seconds difference.

I'm using `java.util.Date`, and cannot use JodaTime.

Any idea where this huge difference is coming from?

Comment: I think there is timezone difference epochTime value and your local. When i print, it shows that time is 2 hours greater than yours because my timezone is different from yours.

Comment: A timezone difference can account for the hours difference you notice, but I ask about the 3 month difference here. There isn't any 3 month difference time-zone :D

Comment: sure :D. Let me check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use lower case y for year

Because upper case Y is Week year and lower case y is year. For more informations see the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
String pattern = "ddMMMyy HH:mm";
```

Comment: Testing this confirms your answer. Yet, the javadoc fails to enlighten me about why a week year and a year would have more than 3 weeks differences…
Actually, what bothers me the most is that the parsing and formatting uses the same format, yet the conversion is way off. Both should be off the epoch time given!